# How to take the derivative of quadratic term that involves vectors, transposes, and matrices, with respect to a scalar

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What are the proper steps to take the derivative with respect to $\alpha$ of

$$\frac 1 2 (x - \alpha g)^T Q (x - \alpha g)$$

to get following?

$$-(x-\alpha g)^T Q g$$

(where $\alpha$ is a scalar, $Q$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, and $x$ and $g$ are vectors of proper size.)

Background and further explanation:

I saw this differentiation as part of a differentiation of a larger expression in Nocedal and Wright's book Numerical Optimization, just above (3.25). The authors skip explaining differentiation steps and obtain the minimizer $\alpha$, as that is their purpose.

When I try to follow I see that the differentiation of this term must yield as above. Now my problem is, if I were to differentiate the term above I would not know that there would be a transpose there, or $Q$ would need to be in the middle. E.g. if everything were scalars the term would be $\frac 1 2 Q (x - \alpha g)^2$, and using the chain rule, I would obtain the derivative as $-Q(x-\alpha g)g$. Now that the vectors and transposes and matrices are involved, how should one apply the chain rule here properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\frac 1 2 \frac{d}{d\alpha}(x - \alpha g)^T Q (x - \alpha g)\\
=& \frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{d\alpha}\left[x^TQx -\alpha x^TQg-\alpha g^TQx + \alpha^2 g^TQg\right]\\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left[-x^TQg-g^TQx + 2\alpha g^TQg\right]\\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left[-x^TQg-x^TQg + 2\alpha g^TQg\right] \quad \text{using Q is symmetric,}\\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left[-2x^TQg + 2\alpha g^TQg\right]\\
=& -x^TQg + \alpha g^TQg\\
=& -(x- \alpha g)^T Qg\\
\end{align}

Edit: Using the product rule.
\begin{align}
&\frac 1 2 \frac{d}{d\alpha}(x - \alpha g)^T Q (x - \alpha g)\\
=& \frac{1}{2}\left[ \left(\frac{d}{d\alpha}(x - \alpha g)^T\right)\cdot Q (x - \alpha g)+(x - \alpha g)^T Q\cdot \frac{d}{d\alpha} (x - \alpha g)\right]\\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left[\left(\frac{d}{d\alpha}(x - \alpha g)\right)^T\cdot Q (x - \alpha g)+(x - \alpha g)^T Q\cdot (- g)\right]\\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left[(-g)^T\cdot Q (x - \alpha g)-(x - \alpha g)^T Q g\right] \\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left[-(g)^T\cdot Q (x - \alpha g)-(x - \alpha g)^T Q g\right]\\
=& \frac{1}{2} \left[-(x - \alpha g)^T\cdot Qg -(x - \alpha g)^T Q g\right] \quad \text{using Q is symmetric,}\\
=& -(x- \alpha g)^T Qg\\
\end{align}

Comment: Would it be possible to do this without doing the multiplication you did in second line?

Comment: @anapprentice As in using a product rule say? Sure. I'll edit now

Comment: @anapprentice how's this?

Comment: Good, thanks. That trick where you used the fact Q is symmetric was what I was missing, I think.

Comment: @anapprentice No problem :) Yeah $Q$ being symmetric means $Q=Q^T$, and since $x^T Q y$ is supposed to be a number say $r=x^T Q y$, then $r^T=r$, and so $r^T=y^TQ^Tx=y^TQx=x^TQy=r$